# Limit ScrollView/List height inside a pre-defined image background

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a design for an android app which has big tables images (see A,B screen below)
this means I already have A and B as images with all sizes that i need (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi):
[image]

My problem is that inside A I need to put a scrollview or a list of items but I don't want them to be bigger than A image.
My current layout is something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        // Some elements here

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        // Some elements here

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/A_background"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/scrollview_container"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/B_background"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When my scrollview has many items, A is expanding, I need A to be the same height as before since the image is getting blurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases I usually end up writing a custom view that measures one view (in this case the ImageView) with MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED and the other one (in your case the ScrollView) with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY or MeasureSpec.AT_MOST (depending on your needs).
Something along the lines:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    // measure view 1
    View view1 = findViewById(R.id.view1);
    view1.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    int view1Height = view1.getMeasuredHeight();

    // check measured height against MeasureSpec and adapt accordingly
    int heightMsrSpec = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    switch (heightMsrSpec) {
    case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST: view1Height = Math.min(height, view1Height); break;
    case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY: view1Height = height; break;
    case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED: break;
    }

    // measure view2
    View view2 = findViewById(R.id.view2);
    view2.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view1Height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    int view2Height = view2.getMeasuredHeight();

    setMeasuredDimension(width, Math.min(view1Height, view2Height) + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom());
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand the last part, how can i pass the right height when i'm using this custom view from my xml? it has wrap_content as I don't know it's height yet.

Comment: The custom view and its parents have an android:layout_height tag as well. Depending on the value of these tags the onMeasure() methods needs to work differently. I added the necessary lines of code to the example.

Comment: The problem in your case is that the RelativeLayout has wrap_content for the height and grows with both the ScrollView and the ImageView but the ScrollView shouldn't be higher than the ImageView. There's no way to configure this requirement in XML unless you set the height of the ScrollView to a fixed value. Hence the custom view which looks more complex but is really easy once you have done it the first time. I've encountered numerous situations where a custom view could cover my requirements easily while the XML couldn't.

Comment: I think i'm missing something, I took your code and created a custom view which extends RelativeLayout and simply put it instead my relative layout in my xml (leaving the scrollview and imageview as they are as children). Is that what you meant? because it seems as the view is not drawing it's children (the scrollview and the imageview) anymore.

Comment: A RelativeLayout doesn't make sense here. Use a FrameLayout because you want to draw the ScrollView on top of the ImageView right?
Also why do you have a android:layout_weight="1" for the RelativeLayout anyway. It shouldn't get larger than the ImageView, right?
If these changes don't work, please upload your complete code someplace so that I can have a look at it.

Comment: Indeed FrameLayout did the trick, thank you very much for the answer and for you patient!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24976/discussion-between-user1955090-and-emanuel-moecklin)

Answer (score 0):

well A is background to the image are you sure this is correct xml file you can't add scrollview inside imageview and it's not inside it either

what you can do is create different res/layout folders like

```
res/layout-small
res/layout-large
res/layout-xlarge
res/layout-sw600
res/layout-sw720
```

place your layout files in them and give absolute hieght to A & B there according to the images you have for them.

This way it won't stretch and will look better on every screen size.

Comment: The scrollview is not inside the imageview, it's inside the relativelayout, I couldn't avoid these imageviews because assigning my A,B images as background to the relativelayouts also stretches them

Comment: Also, how can I avoide duplicating my all xml layout when using different layout folders?

Comment: you can't avoid it if you need multiple screen support and applying the image as the background to the relative layout and assigning hieght and width to the layout wont stretch the image and the layout